# Randomizing questions

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and programming in general. I am working on a trivia game and I would like to randomize my questions so that they are in a different order each time someone plays. Just not sure how to go about it.Thanks for any help.

Comment: Place the questions in a [library container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) ([`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) will probably work best) and run the container through [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please share code.

Comment: user4581301...I looked into what you suggested to see if i can understand it and I believe I do. I just don't know how I would do that. I am new and haven't learned about doing things like that. Sorry to be such a noob. Is the container like a function that I can just call.

Comment: Talha...I haven't tried anything yet. I have looked around on the web and have gotten many different ways.I thought of generating a random number then using a switch to call each question, but that would be a lot of cases. And I wouldn't know how to call up the next question. Again, sorry to be such a noob. This is probably an elementary question.Thank you

Comment: The container is an object that holds other objects. C++ has a whole library of them for a variety of different purposes. They are very trustworthy, quite speedy, most of them are resizable, and they virtually eliminate any memory management woes you'd have if you rolled your own.  If you don't believe me now, you will after the "Write a Linked List" assignment. The problem with random number and `switch` is you have to track which questions you've already asked to prevent repetition. `shuffle` eliminates that problem. You just use the first N items in the list in the shuffled order.

Comment: You can use [std::sample](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) for that.

Comment: Because I'm busy selling the containers library, I didn't mention `shuffle` will work with a dumb, old array, too.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can combine your questions and answers in a single structure to keep them together and then store a bunch of those in a data structure of some kind (like a `std::vector`). Then you can just use `std::shuffle` to randomly rearrange them:

```
// question and answer pairs
struct question_info
{
    std::string Q;
    std::string A;
};

// data structure to store your questions in memory
std::vector<question_info> questions;

// insert some questions (or load them from a file)
questions.push_back({"Why did the chicken cross the road?", "To get to the other side."});
questions.push_back({"Why did the fox cross the road?", "To eat the chicken."});
questions.push_back({"Why did the lemmings cross the road?", "The cliff was on the other side."});

// instantiate a pseudo random number generator
std::mt19937 prng{std::random_device{}()};

// randomly shuffle the questions
std::shuffle(std::begin(questions), std::end(questions), prng);

// print them
for(auto item: questions)
{
    std::cout << "Q: " << item.Q << '\n';
    std::cout << "A: " << item.A << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input. It has been truly helpful.